# "Антропогенно нарушенный" - раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, терминология, раздельно-дефис

"Антропогенно нарушенный" - раздельно или через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

"...Измененные (**антропогенно нарушенные**) почвы - почвы, образующиеся в результате загрязнения, захламления и иного антропогенного воздействия на почвы..." ([Словарь финансовых и юридических терминов)](https://www.consultant.ru/law/ref/ju_dict/word/pochvy_izmenennye_(antropogenno_narushennye)/)

Из Нацкорпуса:

Известно, что кислотность ― информативный показатель состояния **антропогенно нарушенных** почв. [Оценка состояния лесных экосистем, подверженных влиянию урбанистического пресса (2004) // «Лесное хозяйство», 2004.10.19]

---

Логично писать **раздельно**. Нарушенные (как?) антропогенно.

У Розенталя [(§43. Правописание сложных прилагательных](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm#%D0%B7_03)):

*Различаются сложные прилагательные, образующие одно слово (со слитным или дефисным написанием, см. выше), и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о (-е) и прилагательного или причастия (с раздельным написанием); к наречию, играющему роль отдельного члена предложения, можно поставить соответствующий вопрос. Ср.:
морально-этические проблемы – морально устойчивый человек (в каком отношении устойчивый?);
общественно-исторические законы – общественно опасные элементы (опасные для кого?);
промышленно-транспортный отдел – промышленно развитая страна (развитая в каком отношении?).*